Building a Mixed Frequency Function in R
I'm trying to build a mixed frequency time series model in R. I want to set it up such that it has a model frame with data, formula and na.action as is standard (I think) but I'm running into the following issue. I pass my data in as below:
mixed.model(target.series = zoo(x = c(1,2,3), order.by = seq.Date(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-03-01"), by = "month")),
            predictors = zoo(x = data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
    V2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)),
    order.by = seq.Date(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-03-04"), by = "week")))


Unfortunately, when I later run
my.model.frame$data <- data
my.model.frame$formula <- formula
...
my.model.frame <- eval(my.model.frame, parent.frame())

I ultimately get this error:
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 10

This is of course understandable that the underlying R code would check that the predictors and response would match but in this case the mismatch is desired. Is there any way I can circumvent this issue? I've been having a hard time even find resources on how this niche of R programming works so even articles or book recommendations would be helpful.
